# How best to get the slug of an object from a Listview into a Django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a Django ListView/FormView combination where each object in the list on the page has a button that toggles a modal form. The form has a hidden field that I'd like to prepopulate with the slug of the object in the list it came from (ie. not the slug of the page, but of the object in the list on that page). One way I could think of that might work would be to have the {{ form }} tag accept the object's slug as an argument somehow - like {{ form object_instance=object.slug }}. How might I do that? And how might I call it in the ListView?

Thank you for any input you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for initialising a form like this. Assuming that the hidden input field is named `slug` in your form, the code should probably be:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def setslug(form, slugval):
    form.initial['slug'] = slugval
    return form
```

Now you can call it from your template as `{{ form|setslug:slugfield }}`

Comment: This is excellent, and exactly what I was looking for. Incidentally, it works just fine with {{ form|setslug... }} in the template as you answered. However, it errors out with {{ form.as_p|setslug... }} with a "'SafeUnicode' object has no attribute 'initial'" error. It doesn't really matter in my case, but for others who look at this question, I'm not quite sure why that is. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form for each line of the list, just make sure the slug exists in the form's context.

If you have just one form and change its contents based on the user's actions, you'll have to resort to JavaScript.